# how to add restfb. jar to maven project on Apache NetBeans IDE 11.1? No libraries category in Project - >properties

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, restfb

I have a project in which i use Apache Netbeans IDE 11.1 and I want to use Facebook API by adding "restFB.jar" to my project

in previous versions of NetBeans, there was "Libraries" category in Project->Properties

but now in Apache Netbeans IDE 11.1 I can't find the "Libraries" Category .

How can I Add "restFB.jar" to my project in Apache Netbeans IDE 11.1

Below is what I am trying to do. 
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absence of the *Category* named *Libraries* for your project is nothing to do with NetBeans 11.1. Maven projects in any version of NetBeans will not have a *Category* named *Libraries* because it is not needed. Instead, your application's dependencies are specified within **pom.xml**.

You can easily verify this by using the NetBeans project wizard:

- Create a Maven based application (**File > New Project... > Java with Maven > Java Application**).
- Create an Ant based application (**File > New Project... > Java with Ant > Java Application**).
- The Ant application will have a *Category* named *Libraries*, and the Maven project will not.

So to include **restFB.jar** in your Maven project:

- Go to https://mvnrepository.com and search for "*restfb*".
- A list of the possible choices will be shown. You want the topmost one named *RestFB*, so click that.
- On the *RestFB* page the topmost entry is the one you are looking for (*3.0.0-rc.1*), so click that link.
- The `<dependency>` entry you need to add to **pom.xml** will be displayed on the *Maven* tab.
- Click that entry to copy it to the clipboard, then add it to the **pom.xml** for your project and rebuild.

This is [the Maven web page you need](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.restfb/restfb/3.0.0-rc.1) to copy the `<dependency>` entry:

[image: MavenRestFb]

There are [several sample RestFB examples on GitHub](https://github.com/restfb/restfb-examples) which may be helpful. If you get stuck on your own project, try building and running those to help understand and isolate any other issues with your project.